# JavaScript in HTML: Getting undefined input value?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, when I enter a value in the following script, the value of ISBN is always undefined. I'm not sure why this is the case. I have set the button to run the function onclick as well...

**HTML:**

```
<form id="frm1">
    Book ISBN: <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value=行きましょう！>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    var isbn = document.getElementById("frm1").submit(); // Replace with ISBN / EISBN / ASIN of the book
    alert("Starting!");
    alert(isbn);

    var api_key = "cf6f5fe91531a855495d77fc06dd9ada6f1fa1f7"; //Replace with the developer key (Submit the form to get a key)

    //Optional Settings
    var smiley = 'true'; // Change to false if do not want to show smiley with each review
    var width = 700;     // Width of the reviews iframe
    var height = 400;    // Height of the reviews iframe
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    var host = "idreambooks.com";  

    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
              '://' + host + '/reviews_widget.js?api_key=' + api_key + '&isbn=' + isbn +
              '&smiley=' + smiley + '&width=' + width + '&height=' + height;
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing about how to get input values?

Comment: submit() method doesn't have return value, that's why you're getting undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var isbn = document.getElementById('someIdYouAssignTheInput').value;
```

As mentioned above, submit doesn't return anything, which is why the value is undefined. You want to get the *value* of the input element. The best way to do that is to assign it an id, then use the code I included above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

try

```
 var isbn = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
```

to retrieve the input text box's value.